# How to run methods when retrieving data in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an EntityFramework Core model that can run a method:

```
public class Job
{

    public int JobId

    public string Image

    public string GetJobImage()
    {            
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Image))
        {
                return "/assets/img/generic-photo-placeholder.png";
        }
        else if (Image == "Custom")
        {
            return string.Format("/JobImages/{0}", JobId);
        }
        return ""; 
    }
}
```

When I run a query to get a Job in EF, how do I always get the results of this method?

Comment: change it to a readonly property

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "always get the results"? Just call the method or do I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: What have you tried in the controller ? Please show some relevant code .